# cblas ImportError after installing sklearn using dokku

Tags: numpy, heroku, scipy, scikit-learn, dokku

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy) Heroku buildpack to install numpy and scipy. Then, I am able to just pip install sklearn from my requirements.txt file during the push deployment.

It appears to install fine, but I run into various errors in files due to imports.

They all ultimately yield an ImportError of:

`undefined symbol: cblas_dscal`

or

`undefined symbol: cblas_dasum`

Does anyone have any insight on how to resolve this?